# Insertion error in Binary Search tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

```
void BST::insert(string word)
{
   insert(buildWord(word),root);
}
  //Above is the gateway insertion function that calls the function below
  //in order to build the Node, then passes the Node into the insert function
  //below that

Node* BST::buildWord(string word)
{
   Node* newWord = new Node;
   newWord->left = NULL;
   newWord->right = NULL;
   newWord->word = normalizeString(word);

   return newWord;
}
   //The normalizeString() returns a lowercase string, no problems there

void BST::insert(Node* newWord,Node* wordPntr)
{
  if(wordPntr == NULL)
  {
  cout << "wordPntr is NULL" << endl;
  wordPntr = newWord;
  cout << wordPntr->word << endl;
  }
  else if(newWord->word.compare(wordPntr->word) < 0)
  {
     cout << "word alphabetized before" << endl;
     insert(newWord,wordPntr->left);
  }
  else if(newWord->word.compare(wordPntr->word) > 0)
  {
     cout << "word alphabetized after" << endl;
     insert(newWord, wordPntr->right);
  }
  else
  {
     delete newWord;
  }
}
```

So my problem is this: I call the gateway insert() externally (also no problems with the inflow of data) and every time it tells me that the root, or the initial Node* is NULL. But that should only be the case before the first insert. Each time the function is called, it sticks the newWord right at the root.
To clarify: These functions are part of the BST class, and root is a Node* and a private member of BST.h

It's possible it is quite obvious, and I have just been staring too long. Any help would be appreciated.
Also, this is a school-assigned project.

Best

Comment: How are you initializing the root node?

Comment: The root Node is initialized to NULL in the constructor:

Comment: BST::BST()
    {
    chooseRight = true;
    root = NULL;

    }

Comment: And is root ever pointed to anything except NULL?

Comment: The Only time it is pointed to NULL is when the constructor is called implicitly via instantiation of the BST class, which happens only once. @JackRadcliffe

Comment: Yes, but then is it ever redirected AFTER the constructor is called?  It's only going to tell you that root points to NULL if it points to NULL, mind you.

Comment: The insert function passes the root into the second insert function as the Node* wordPntr. The first time it is passed after class instantiation it should be NULL, in which case wordPntr = newWord; and root should no longer be NULL. I know it is, but I don't know why, obviously. @JackRadcliffe

Comment: But are you sure that setting wordPntr equal to newWord also sets the private variable root equal to newWord?  That isn't a trick question.  I haven't worked with C++/pointers for a couple months so I don't quite remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like user946850 says, the variable `wordPntr` is a local variable, if you change it to point to something else it will not be reflected in the calling function.

There are two ways of fixing this:

1. The old C way, by using a pointer to a pointer:

   ```
   void BST::insert(Node *newWord, Node **wordPntr)
   {
       // ...
       *wordPntr = newWord;
       // ...
   }
   ```

   You call it this way:

   ```
   some_object.insert(newWord, &rootPntr);
   ```
2. Using C++ references:

   ```
   void BST::insert(Node *newWord, Node *&wordPntr)
   {
       // Nothing here or in the caller changes
       // ...
   }
   ```

To help you understand this better, I suggest you read more about scope and lifetime of variables.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `wordPntr = newWord;` is local to the `insert` function, it should somehow set the root of the tree in this case.

Comment: But the root is a Node* and a private member of the BST class and newWord is a dynamically allocated memory location, so root should be pointing to newWord even after the completion of the function.